# Symfony MySQL subquery best practice : Native, QueryBuilder or DQL

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

Here is a simple MySQL query i want to use in a Symfony2 project :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT n.sdate, n.edate FROM `news` n 
    UNION 
    SELECT ss.sdate, ss.edate FROM `stagesession` ss
) AS sub 
ORDER BY sub.sdate
```

In fact, this query will be a little more complicated, with more aliases, filter and joins with other tables.

Do I have to convert it in a DQL query, with the createQueryBuilder, or the best way is simply to use createNativeQuery from doctrine ?

Comment: some queries like above which are complex in nature is better to use native query instead of query builder.

Answer (score 1):

My personal Best Practice with Doctrine is:

**Query (QB vs. DQL vs. SQL):**

- use QB if building your query is more conditional than just passing some parameters, like `if($onlyActive) $qb->andWhere('x.type = 5');` (I don't like string concat stuff)
- use QB for compatibility reasons to pagination toolkits
- use DQL for simple selects
- use SQL if DQL-query not possible (e.g. DB-native expressions MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL, some weird statistics or hacky queries with UNION or huge subqueries)
- at least you can also use SQL, if you're using a small data subset of a very huge DB (like writing some plugin software), because else if the database schema is quite small, you could create some entities from it and revalidate them (for example when you deploy) as a system-test. But if it's too complicated then QB or DQL would also be overkill for accessing such a database, because you have to define entities to work.

**Result (orm vs. flat):**

- use ORM in business code wherever possible to have max. readable code (consider lazy loading)
- use ORM in complicated nested views (no huge tables) to have nice clean code in your template (consider eager loading)
- use flat arrays for read-only tables/lists
- use flat arrays for optimization reasons when dealing with lot's of data (and caching not possible)

And always keep in mind, that you should first write simple code and iff it's to slow, optimize it with eager/lazy loading, Query/Result caching, HTTP caching and at least if you e.g. deal with some database synchronization or data importer you may have use flat arrays or fall back to native implementations, but don't underrate ORM ;).